# json String in android

Tags: android

I have a problem while creating jsonStringer in android. My problem is I have to post values to server using post method.So for that I have to send an array. `{ "name":"asdf","age":"42","HaveFiles":["abcfile","bedFile","cefFile"]}` .

So how can I create a json array for haveFiles? And I don't know the no of files it may varies. So I am creating a string builder and appending the values to that. 
when I print the jsonString the stringbuilder show that instead of `"` it shows `\"`. But when I print the string builder it looks `["abcFile"]` like this. but in jsonStringer it prints `["\""abcFile\""]`. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation regarding JSONArray? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create json object and pass the json object

```
   try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(YourString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

If you want jsonArray then

`jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);`

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple, you can use [**GSON library**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to do it.

The usage is something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(yourObj);
YourObjType yourObj2 = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, YourObjType.class);
```

Regarding to your situation, you can do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] ss = new String[] {"abcFile", "defFile", "ghiFile"};
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(ss);
```

And the result of jsonStr is:

```
["abcFile, defFile, ghiFile"]
```

Comment: What...? GSON is not for this purpose.

Comment: have to use json only.Otherwise can you send me an example

Comment: . If you are sending more information to server you library:jackson or gson

Comment: @Srikanth I am a little bit confused here, you are talking about you have problems when converting objects to json. But I have tried with GSON it is pretty good. What do you mean by "json only"? GSON is the best json serializer/deserializer on Android.

Comment: could you please create a sample for my object?

Comment: ` stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append("\"" +value+"\"");  String fileArray = "[" + stringBuilder.toString()+"]";  jSONStringer = new JSONStringer().object()
        .key("name")
        .value(nameTextView.getText().toString())
        .key("age").value(itemvalue).key("HaveFiles")
        .value(fileArray).endObject();  while printing the jsonstringer I got the "name":"asdf","age":"42","HaveFiles":["[\""abcfile\",\"bedFile\",\"cefFile\"]"}` like this

Comment: @Srikanth I have modified the answer, but not sure if it is the answer you want.

Comment: I cant pass that value to post method.I can pass only in the jsonstringer.

Comment: I don't know what kind of http post method are you using? With org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost you can easily add any entity into the post content.

Comment: And here i dont know the exact size of the array, to avoid this I used to convert it into to a string. while passing that value to jsonstringer it show backslash.How can i Remove that